# Move focus to first column of new row in DataGrid (WPF)

Tags: wpf, datagrid, focus, wpfdatagrid, wpftoolkit

I am binding a `DataTable` to a `DataGrid`(WPF toolkit) for add, edit and delete. I am able to use tab keys to navigate through the cells from top to bottom. But as soon as I press tab on last rows' last column, it is not taking the cursor to the first cell of new row. How can I achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Is this sorted out by any way? Can you please share your experience on this? I'm also facing same problem.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Cycle"?

Answer (score 0):

I would try a keydown event that checks for the tab key and checks to see if it is the last column # if so it would go to the first column in the next row.

Answer (score -4):

Please check this:

A datagrid has a property `CanUserAddRows`. Set `in` to `true`:

```
CanUserAddRows="True"
```

The mode of databinding should be `TwoWay`:

```
Mode="TwoWay"
```